# Dynamically create a nested JavaScript object with unknown keys

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have two arrays which are returned in a response from a REST call. For simplification I defined them hard-coded as `keys` and `subKeys` in the following example code.

From these arrays I'd like to create a nested object which, when outputted as a JSON string, looks like this:

**Target JSON**

```
{
    "key1": {
        "subKey1": "someValue"
    },
    "key2": {
        "subKey2": "someValue"
    },
    "key3": {
        "subKey3": "someValue"
    }
}
```

**Code sample**

```
var keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"];  // These come from a REST response
var subKeys = ["subKey1", "subKey2", "subKey3"]; // These come from a REST response

var targetObj = {}
for (const key in keys) {      
  targetObj[key] = {}
  for (const subKey in subKeys) {
    targetObj[key][subKey] = "someValue";
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(targetObj, null, 2));
```

While this gives me the correct behavior in my application I have the impression that there might be simpler approaches to achieve the same result, either in "vanilla" JavaScript or ES6? What bothers me here is that I define an empty object in each run of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not produce the example output you said you want. It will put all 3 subkeys under each key, not one per key. Also you end up with numeric keys, not the key names.

```js
var keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"];  // These come from a REST response
var subKeys = ["subKey1", "subKey2", "subKey3"]; // These come from a REST response

var targetObj = {}
for (let i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {    
  const key = keys[i];
  targetObj[key] = { [subKeys[i]]: "someValue" };
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(targetObj, null, 2));
```

First you were using "in" instead of "of" in the for-loop, and secondly you were not using the same index to find the subkey.

To avoid creating an empty object you can use this syntax:

```
{ [variable]: "value" }
```

This creates the object with the variable value as the key, and a string as the value. Putting the variable name in square brackets tells it to use the variable value rather than its name.  Saying `{ variable: "value" }` wouldn't work because the key would be "variable" not the value of `variable`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [Array.prototype.reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"];
const subKeys = ["subKey1", "subKey2", "subKey3"];

const result = keys.reduce((acc, key, index) =>
   ({ ...acc, [key]: { [subKeys[index]]: 'someValue' } })
, {});
```

Note, this works only if `keys` and `subKeys` arrays are synced and their indexes are consistent with each other.